# Bind a collection to columns in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

Usually we bind a collection to pre-defined columns of wpf data grid. Now requirement is little different.

I have a collection which contains Actors info. And I have a collection which have departments.

I want to create a checkbox column for each actor and put them against departments and check/uncheck based on their skills level. Sample image is attached

[image]

Comment: Create a model class with a property per actor + department or use a DataTable.

Comment: @mm8 Actors are coming from database, it could be any random thing. I think I can create a class by using reflection and adding one property per actor (based on the collection). That seems like a lot of work for such simple requirement. Approach of using datatable could be used but it'll be better  if I can find something else rather than relying on datatable for easy binding and management for later actions.

Answer (score 1):

You could refer this [link](https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/4-steps-to-creating-an-inverted-datagrid) . It guide for C1-WPF but I think the idea for WPF standard is similar